# How do I center my dropdown menu?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, themes, center

I'm trying to center my dropdown menu without it affecting the functions of the menu. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

```
#menu_container { padding: 1px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; }
#menu_container ul { list-style-type: none; }
#menu_container ul li { float: left; font-size: 12px; position: relative; }
#menu_container ul li a { display: block; padding: 5px 15px; color: #808080; text-decoration: none; }
#menu_container ul li a:hover { background-color: #333; color: #808080; }
#menu_container ul li ul { display: none; position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 0; z-index: 150; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
#menu_container ul li ul li { width: 310px; float: none; }
#menu_container ul li ul li a { background-color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your layout and page structure. It might be as simple as assigning #menu_container a fixed-width and automatic margins:

```
#menu_container { width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 1px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; }
/* Depending on your layout, you may also need to assign a full-width and/or relative positioning to a parent/container/wrapper element */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the #menu_container element to center by adding

```
margin:0px auto;
```

In order for that to work, you will also have to set a width for the container.